# JSQMessagesViewController without cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Did anyone tried to install JSQMessagesViewController manually without using cocoa pods?
I tried to download JSQMessagesViewController project and add its sdk to my project but it's not working... Do I need to add some binaries?

Step by step what I have done:

1. I cloned project from GitHub
2. Copied downloaded project folder to my project folder
3. Opened the new downloaded folder, and dragged the JSQMessages.xcodeproj into the Project Navigator of my application's Xcode project
4. the same I've done with JSQSystemSoundPlayer
5. I added `#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>` to bridging header

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: Read installation guide carefully and if you are getting any error then attach screen shot or more detail on SO so that it can be answered.

Comment: If you're using swift you need to create a bridging header and import it to your project by adding this to your bridging header `#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>`

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman I edited my question.

Comment: @DatForis it did not help... I edited my answer and added some more info

Comment: @birdy Better to install with Cocoapods. It's not hard, all you have to do is add it to your Podfile.

How did you integrate it into the project manually without configuring your Build Phases on Xcode?

Comment: @Alex7 I decided to use another framework. 
I know that it's not hart to install with cocoapods, that was not a problem :D but in my case I used carthage for my project and it needs to be without cocoapods. That's it.

Comment: @birdy what other library did u use?

Comment: @Kashif first I thought I t would be good to use NoChat, but still it's not quite good solution in my case.

Comment: @birdy Did you find a way to install JSQ without pod?

Comment: @Kashif nope...